# Mac Mini without keyboard or mouse - no signal on monitor

Tags: mac-mini, hdmi, remote-desktop

I have decided to turn my old [Mac Mini (2011)](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp632?locale=en_US) into home media center.

To do that I simply connected it to TV using HDMI cable (directly via HDMI port) and installed [Remote Mouse](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote-mouse/id403195710?mt=12) on it as well as corresponding app on my iPhone.

Now if I use Remote Desktop / Teamviewer app - I can wake up this Mac Mini and can use Remote Mouse app from phone to control it without any problem (rather flawlessly).

However without Remote Desktop app nothing seems to wake up this Mac. It does not even show screensaver (sleep is disabled), it is just "no signal" on TV and remote mouse from phone has no effect.

I tried to change TV connection from HDMI port to Thundebolt port (thunderbolt to HDMI adapter), however this does not change anything.

I have also tried using my Bluetooth mouse connected with Mac Mini, but this also does not change anything, mouse shows it is connected, but "no signal" on TV.

Anything am I missing there?

Comment: if it's not asleep, but the screen has gone off, see the display sleep time in sys prefs>Energy Saver. Since about Mavericks, once that kicks in you need to tap Spacebar to wake, shaking the mouse no longer works.

Comment: @Tetsujin display settings are set to never off. It must show screensaver. Moreover if I can Remote Desktop connected it actually shows screensaver and then I can wake it up with mouse. The problem is that it does not activate when there is no Remote Desktop, so it is something different. Also waking up with mouse works well for me on my MacBook and High Sierra